# How to get all SPWebs using visual studio?

Tags: spweb, spsite, spwebcollection

I want to get all webs including it's subwebs.

Eg.

1. Site

   1. web1

      1. subweb1
      2. subweb2
   2. web2

How to achieve ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one solution, which will return all sites including its subsite.

```
SPWebCollection allwebcoll = spsite.AllWebs;
```

Comment: mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Its all happening in [SharePoint Manager](http://spm.codeplex.com/), just download source code and look at code to get what you want.

Hope it helps :).

Answer (score 1):

you can use [WebsInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spwebcollection.websinfo.aspx) property of SPWebCollection class

```
var list = SPContext.Current.Site.AllWebs.WebsInfo;
```

then you can perform action with [SPWebInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spwebinfo.aspx) class.